# Unable to click button in popup using webdriver

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click a button using selenium webdriver. Working fine with the following XPath

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[36]/div[3]/div/button[1]")).click();
```

it clicks the button fine but if I try to find it using class then it wont click it

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']/button[1]")).click();
```

Any Idea what I am doing wrong. Actual source code is as follows:-

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">

    ::before
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
        <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">

    <span class="ui-button-text"></span>

</button>
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">

                <span class="ui-button-text"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        ::after
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The path expressions look fine. Sure that they are equivalent? (Alternatively, show more of the input document to let others help find out.)

Answer (score 0):

I see two buttons with the same class name. You could try this:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("button[class=\"ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only\"]"));
//click on the first button
list.get(0).click();
```

Comment: This will work? if class name with space. I don't think so. Could you correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Ya you might be right. A cssSelector or Xpath query would work though - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475449/webdriver-classname-with-space-using-java

Answer (score 0):

you can try the contains operator "*" of css selector.

```
 List<WebElement> mylist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("button[class*='ui-corner-all']"));
    mylist[0].click();
```

you can visit this link for CSS Selector tutorial in Selenium with c#

http://binaryclips.com/2015/02/16/css-selectors-for-selenium-webdriver/