# Webdriver: How to find elements when class name contains space?

Tags: python, css, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Each of the "7-pack" search results [here](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=plumbers%2Bhouston%2Btx) contains a number of reviews e.g. "5 reviews", No reviews" etc.

The class name for each is `fl r-iNTHbQvDybDU`. It contains a space, so if I try find_elements_by_class_name(), I get:

```
InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted
```

According to other answers on here, all I needed to do was remove the space and retry. No luck - an empty list

So I try `find_element_by_css_selector()`:

```
find_elements_by_css_selector(".fl.r-iNTHbQvDybDU")
```

Still no luck - empty list. What would you try next?

Comment: The string after **r-** looks like randomly generated to ensure uniqueness. I think that's why you cannot get anything.

Comment: Maybe this also helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475449/webdriver-classname-with-space-using-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not rely on the auto-generated class names like these. Aside from being non-reliable, it is making your code less readable. Instead, get the *links containing "review" text*.

Combined solution with the [Webdriver/Selenium: How to find element when it has no class name, id, or css selecector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075506/webdriver-selenium-how-to-find-element-when-it-has-no-class-name-id-or-css-se/31076043#31076043) thread:

```
import re

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException    
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=plumbers%2BAvondale%2BAZ')

# waiting for results to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
box = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "lclbox")))

phone_re = re.compile(r"\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}")

for result in box.find_elements_by_class_name("intrlu"):
    for span in result.find_elements_by_tag_name("span"):
        if phone_re.search(span.text):
            parent = span.find_element_by_xpath("../..")
            print parent.text
            break

    try:
        reviews = result.find_element_by_partial_link_text("review").text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        reviews = "0 Google reviews"

    print reviews
    print "-----"
```

Prints:

```
360 N Central Ave
Avondale, AZ
(623) 455-6605
1 Google review
-----
Avondale, AZ
(623) 329-5170
4 Google reviews
-----
Tolleson, AZ
(623) 207-1995
7 Google reviews
-----
3947 N 146th Dr
Goodyear, AZ
(602) 446-6576
1 Google review
-----
564 W Western Ave
Goodyear, AZ
(623) 455-6605
0 Google reviews
-----
14190 W Van Buren St
Goodyear, AZ
(623) 932-5300
0 Google reviews
-----
```

Comment: Thanks, but this also returns an empty list. If I shorten the partial text to just "reviews", still an empty list. The element is a *<span>* - does *find_elements_by_partial_link_text()* only work for *<a>*?

Comment: @Pyderman updated, you just need to explicitly wait for the results to load.

Comment: @alexce Thanks - this has been working well, in most cases. But when a search returns some results that don't have any reviews (see https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=plumbers%2BAvondale%2BAZ for an example), it breaks down, as it only extracts those that have a "* Google reviews" element

Comment: @alexce So in the cases where a result has no reviews, there is no span of style *white-space:nowrap* for that div of class "intrlu". How would we apply your approach given in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31076043/1389110 here? i.e. how can we extract (i) those spans (when they are present) and (ii) somehow apply a value of "0 reviews" where the span is not present for a given result?

Comment: @Pyderman I would search for the `review` partial link text inside each result and catch the `NoSuchElementException` which would mean we've got 0 reviews. I've updated the code in this answer. Also, fixed the problem with a single google review (searching for `review` instead of `reviews`). Thanks.

Comment: Belated thanks, @alecxe, this has been working nicely.

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='fl r-iNTHbQvDybDU']")
```

This assumes tag for the `class = div`.

If it is something else - otherwise replace div w/ the appropriate tag..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find_elements_by_css_selector(".r-iNTHbQvDybDU")
```

Comment: Thanks. Return an empty list though.

Answer (score 1):

U need to add the tag name in front of it.

For Example, it is inside a div element, then:

```
Selenium.find_element_by_class_name(div.ur.class.name)
```