# Unable to locate the Element on Canvas using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, canvas, selenium-webdriver, action, polygon

I have an application developed by using Vaadin Framework, Now i need to click on the rectangular polygon which is on the Canvas.following is the html code 
here i am providing the Html code

```
<canvas width="1920" height="524" class="ol-unselectable" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas>
```

and i tried by using Actions which makes the mouse move over the Polygon and click .

```
int x = (int) 5638326.333511386;
int y = (int)  2580101.9711508946;
driver.get("http://localhost:8080/internship");

WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//canvas[@class='ol-unselectable']"));
        //  driver.findElement(By.tagName("canvas"));
        //driver.findElemet(By.className("ol-unselectable"));
try {
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(ele, x, y);
    builder.clickAndHold();
    builder.release();
    builder.perform();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // do nothing
    }
```

i am getting the foloowing error

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   //canvas[@class='ol-unselectable'].

can anyone suggest some samples how to find polygon on canvas with co-ordinates and make click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the canvas element is embedded in an iframe.
So, first, you have to find the iframe element and then find the canvas inside the iframe. For instance:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
        try {
            driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_empty");
            WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.name("iframeResult"));
            driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
            WebElement canvas = driver.findElement(By.id("myCanvas"));
            System.out.println(canvas.getText());
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
```

I think this code might help you.

**EDIT:**
After chatting with @RamanaMuttana and his changes on the posted question, I could better understand his need.

We realized that just using the By.tagName selector was enough to find the canvas element as in the code bellow:

```
driver.findElements(By.tagName("canvas")).get(0);
```

Comment: now i am able to go to iframe after that ,i am not able to find the WebElement canvas =driver.findElement(By.className(" .ol-unselectable"); i am getting error as  "Unable to find element with css selector == .ol-unselectable ". do you have any idea ,Do i need to use javascript executor to find element ?

Comment: In your HTML code, there is no dot  (.) before the class name. It is just ol-unselectable.

Comment: sorry in my  Test code also there is no "." it is only my mistake here when i am giving the comment

Comment: Another option might be to use By.cssselector as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475449/webdriver-classname-with-space-using-java .

Comment: i tried with the the following but  got unable to find the element     WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class='ol-unselectable']"));
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("canvas[class='ol-unselectable']"));
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("canvas.ol-unselectable"));
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//canvas[@class='ol-unselectable']"));
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//canvas[text() = 'ol-unselectable']"));

Comment: Try using By.tagName like: driver.findElements(By.tagName("canvas")).get(0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167816/discussion-between-ramanamuttana-and-thiago-procaci).