# $(".navbar.navbar-inverse").click() works but $(".navbar .navbar-inverse").click() does not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm still learning the ropes of web design, and I am having trouble understanding how a couple of things work...

I created a function to toggle the navbar header background color, and I'm finding the following to be true but unsure why:

Works:

```
$(".navbar.navbar-inverse".click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

Does not work (space btw navbar and navbar-inverse):

```
$(".navbar .navbar-inverse".click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    });
```

Similarly, if I apply this function to the navbar-toggle, the opposite is true:

Works (space btw navbar and navbar-toggle):

```
$(".navbar .navbar-toggle").click(function() {
              $(".navbar-inverse").toggleClass("highlight");
          });
```

Does not work:

```
$(".navbar.navbar-toggle").click(function() {
                  $(".navbar-inverse").toggleClass("highlight");
              });
```

Bonus...

Cannot change navbar-toggle background using this approach:

Does not work:

```
$(".navbar .navbar-toggle").click(function() {
              $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
          });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one refers an element with classes `navbar` and `navbar-toggle`, the second one refers `.navbar-toggle` which is a descendant of `.navbar`. That's what putting a space does :)

Comment: Thank you! Any suggestions as to why the last bit does not work - cannot change the background color of the navbar-toggle button using the method described? Or, do you need more code for that one?

Comment: @Nate Try removing space?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Here is my jsfiddle if that helps:

https://jsfiddle.net/m9m9q8mo/2/

Comment: @Nate Anyway, that's a separate problem. You could ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1988486/6640049), you can select elements (e.g. named "navbar") that contain a specific class ("navbar-inverse") with "navbar.navbar-inverse". If you add a whitespace between those two, it basically means

*Select all elements that have the class navbar-inverse and are children of the navbar*

Cheers

Comment: The answer link was very helpful, thanks! Marking nicael's correct, though, just for succinctness.